# ¿Cómo hacer que el width de un input aumente mientras se escribe en él?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el width de un input aumente mientras escriba en él? A continuación de él tengo un button que se desplazaría cuando el width del input aumente.

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <input id="text_input" placeholder="Escriba el texto..." 
  type="text"/>
  <button id="add_button">Añadir</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando `Javascript` puro, podrías hacerlo así:

#### Demo:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('text_input'),
  // Guardamos el ancho inicial
  minWidth = input.clientWidth;

// Cada vez que se ingrese un valor en el input
input.addEventListener('input', updateWidth);

// Inicializamos el input con el ancho necesario
updateWidth();

//
function updateWidth() {
  // Establecemos el ancho inicial
  input.style.width = minWidth + 'px';

  // Si el ancho interno es mayor al ancho externo
  if (input.scrollWidth > input.clientWidth) {
    // Establecemos el ancho interno
    input.style.width = input.scrollWidth + 'px';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <input id="text_input" placeholder="Escriba el texto..." type="text" />
  <button id="add_button">Añadir</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Bueno, a mi me funciona perfecto así que gracias, muchas gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: Genial respuesta! +1 por lo de `scrollWidth`. Lo único que yo inicializaría el ancho inicial del input fuera del evento input. Ya que al escribir la primera letra el input se hace un poco más grande (Al menos en mi navegador).

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, he actualizado mi respuesta para dar una solución al problema que comentas y a la posibilidad de que el `input` tenga un `value` por defecto.